# Run event triggered function only once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

**UPDATE:**

The thumb image a tag hover invokes a function called `displayImage()`:

```
    function displayImage(index, parent){
    var images = document.getElementById(parent).getElementsByClassName("mainProductImage");
        
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      var image = images[i];
      if (image.className != 'mainProductImage')  { continue }
      if(i == index-1) {
            // display main image
        image.style.display="block";
            // change selectedIndex of select list 
        jQuery("#mySelect").attr('selectedIndex', index-1);
        jQuery('#mySelect').trigger('change', [ i ]);           
      }
      else {
        image.style.display="none";
      }     
   }
}
```

I realize I did not explain this very well :)
I have `n` number of image thumbnails that when hovered change the main product image on the page.  The thumbnail hover event sends a `trigger()` to the select list on the same page (a drop-down with the `n` number of products where, if there are 3 images, there are 3 corresponding product items on the select list).

Based on Patrick's suggestion I first added this to the loop when one hovers the thumbnails:

```
jQuery('#mySelect').trigger('change', [ i ]); // now passing the i variable
```

Then I added:

```
$('#mySelect').change( function( event, idx ) {
if( idx === 0 ) {
   $('#fade').fadeOut('fast');
   $('#fade').fadeIn('slow');
}
```

This code is now limiting the number of image fades when I hover on a thumbnail, but still fades twice for some reason, not just once.

I also would like the image fade effect to occur when I change the product items in the select list, but that's not working right now since the `.change()` function does not recognize the `[i]` from the loop array.  So I need a solution that will trigger the fade when one hovers on the thumbnails OR when one changes the product select list items.

I hope this makes some sense!

---

Is there a way to run jQuery code inside a regular JavaScript function only once?

I have a `fadeImage()` function that is invoked for image transitioning purposes based on different events on the page.  One of these events is triggered from a for loop.  The loop is causing the function to be invoked many times, so the fading in and out of the images loops until the loop is done.  I need to fire the fading effect from inside the loop but only once, so I was hoping instead of changing anything in the loop area, to have the fading function run only once no matter what.

I tried [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) but no luck.

```
function fadeImage()
{
    // is there a way to run these two lines only once? 
    $('#fade').fadeOut('fast');
    $('#fade').fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.  Or any other ideas, maybe I don't need a function at all to wrap the jQuery code?

Comment: So hovering a thumbnail updates the main product image, and changes the selected item in the `<select>` to match the thumbnail. Is that right? If so, where does the `for` loop come into play?

Comment: On thumbnail hover a function, displayImage(), is invoked.  Code on main post :)

Comment: First, off topic but are you aware that `getElementsByClassName` is not supported in IE? Anyway, I see what you're doing now, and the extra parameters solution won't work like that. The issue doesn't seem to be with the `for` loop, since the `.change()` event only happens once in the loop. Instead (if I'm understanding) the issue is that the user may rapidly move from one thumbnail to another before the animation has a chance to complete. If that sounds right, just try using `.stop()` or `stop(true,true)` with your `fadeIn/Out` calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comment below, it sounds like in the `for` loop, you're triggering a `.change()` event several times.

If you use `.trigger()` instead of `.change()`, you can send "extra parameters" to the handler in an Array.

So your `for` loop would be something like:

```
var myselect = $('#mySelect');

for( var i = 0; i < something.length; i++ ) {
    myselect.trigger( 'change', [ i ] );
    // ...and so on
}
```

then your handler would be set up with a parameter to accept that `i` argument.

```
$('#mySelect').change( function( event, idx ) {
    if( idx === 0 ) {
       $('#fade').fadeOut('fast');
       $('#fade').fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
```

---

In your `for` loop, you could set a variable as a flag indicating that it has already been called.

```
var alreadyCalled = false;

for( /* whatever */ ) {
    if( !alreadyCalled ) {
        fadeImage();
        alreadyCalled = true;
    }
    // ...and so on
}
```

Another option would be to have your function accept a parameter of the index in the `for` loop, which it uses to determine if the code should run.

```
function fadeImage( idx ) {
    if( idx === 0 ) {
       $('#fade').fadeOut('fast');
       $('#fade').fadeIn('slow');
    }
}

for( var i = 0; i < something.length; i++ ) {
    fadeImage( i );
    // ...and so on
}
```

The upside is less variable clutter. Downside is unnecessary function calls.

Comment: Thanks Patrick this should work but I should have explained my case better in my post ... the for loop sends a change event to a select list which in turn calls the fadeImage() function. The loop is sending change events to the select list n times. So, the select list is invoking fadeImage() n times.  So I need to make it run once, but after the loop ... hope this makes sense

Comment: When you say "sends a change event", do you mean you're calling `.change()` on the select? If so, you could use my second example by passing "extra parameters" to the event handler if you use `.trigger()`. So do `select.trigger('change', [i])` (notice `i` is in an Array). Then have the event handler accept that parameter. (Remember, the `event` object is always the first parameter.) I'll update my answer in a minute.

Comment: Patrick, thanks a ton!  This looks right but still not working for me.  Updating my post with more info.